# Transparency towards parent, but not towards another elements

Tags: css, z-index, opacity

Is there any way to make semi-transparent overlapping elements, from which only higher z-index will be visible? I would like the images to be transparent to the background, but not to the other pictures. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5bkdbpn/1/) is fiddle.

```css
body {
   background: white;
}

section {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 500px;
}

img {
    height: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
    width: 200px;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
  left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 3;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 45%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 2;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  left: 60%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
<img src="https://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2016_36/1685951/ss-160826-twip-05_8cf6d4cb83758449fd400c7c3d71aa1f.nbcnews-ux-2880-1000.jpg">
<img src="http://toprozdily.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slon-africky.jpg">
<img src="http://img.huffingtonpost.com/asset/,scalefit_950_800_noupscale/55fc14631c00004800082775.jpeg">
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Now we know where, post an image showing how it should look like instead

Comment: Btw, this might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode ... https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're going to need to do is put the images each in their own `div` container and set the `div` background-color to white. That way you see the white background through the semi-opaque images and not the image underneath.

I edited your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalenconner/vo72rsts/) to give you the functionality you're looking for. Hope it helps!

Comment: Although it only works if the background has one color, but it's enough for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to make an element be transparent to one element but opaque to another.

However, you might be able to simulate the transparency by tinting the images instead, either by positioning a partially-transparent div of that color over each image, or with CSS filters:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp